# Generating and Storing Samples of an Exponential Distribution with a name for each sample using a loop

Tags: python

I've got a weird question for a class project. Assuming X ~ Exp(Lambda), Lambda=1.6, I have to generate 100 samples of X, with the indices corresponding to the sample size of each generated sample (S1, S2 ... S100). I've worked out a simple loop which generate the required samples in array, but i am not able to rename the array.

First attempt:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    samples = []
    for i in range(1,101,1):
        samples.append(np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.6, size= i))
```

Second attempt:

```js
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(1,101,1):
    samples = np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.2, size= i)
    col = f'samples {i}'
    df_samples[col] = exponential_sample
    
df_samples = pd.DataFrame(samples)
```

An example how I would like to visualize the data:

```js
# drawing 50 random samples of size 2 from the exponentially distributed population
sample_size = 2
df2 = pd.DataFrame(index= ['x1', 'x2'] )

for i in range(1, 51):
    exponential_sample = np.random.exponential((1/rate), sample_size)
    col = f'sample {i}'
    df2[col] = exponential_sample

# Taking a peek at the samples
df2
```

But instead of having a simple size = 2, I would like to have sample size = i. This way, I will be able to generate 1 rows for the first column (S1), 2 rows for the second column (S2), until I reach 100 rows for the 100th column (S100).

Comment: You are not able to rename the array ? What do you mean ?

Comment: @CyDevos I want have the col name like this: S100, S200, S300, ..., "S10100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot stick vectors of different lengths easily into a df so your mock-up code would not work, but you can `concat` one vector at a time:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(100,10100,100):
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({f'S{i}':np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.2, size= i)})
    df = pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Consider 'accepting' the answer per the guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @pitebarg For a reason I don't know I can't "accept" your answer. This is why I said "Thank you very much"... But the 2 others answers I can but not yours. Also, if you check, there are a total of 2 answers but yours is not included in it. May be there is a glitch...This is my first post by the way....

Comment: @Python_Guy maybe the header in the middle of the answer was confusing, I cleaned it up. and welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Use a dict instead maybe?

```py
    samples = {}
    for i in range(100,10100,100):
        samples[i] = np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.2, size= i)
```

Then you can convert it into a `pandas` Dataframe if you like.